# website 404 error from external webbrowser

Tags: xampp, http-status-code-404, external

I can't get access to my website from external over the ip adress.
this works:

```
localhost/my_website  // shows my web_site
https://IP-adress/    // I see xampp startpage
```

this doesn't work:

```
 https://IP-adress/my_website //-> I get 404 error
```

when i add to the httpd.config file "listen 443" or "listen 80" the server doesn't start.
info: I'm using lubuntu(ubuntu)

**Edit:**
at pre-conclusion at least it has nothing to do with "listen "

The point is that just the folder /my_website,which shows **my_website can't be shown from external computer,but xampp for an example is shown from external**
I

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably need to specify a host address, as well as a port. It's been a few years since I used xampp, but I'm guessing it defaults to localhost if no address is explicitly provided.

So, rather than "listen 80"/"listen 443", try "`listen <ip address>:80`"/"`listen <ip address>:443`".

For example: "listen 0.0.0.0:80" would allow you to reach your server from your local machine using both localhost and 127.0.0.1.

Comment: unfortunately the server doesn't start if I add this  :( log says: (98)Address already in use: AH00072: make_sock: could not bind to address

Comment: sounds like another server process (or an existing instance of this server) is already running. this command should reveal the process: sudo netstat -ltnp | grep ':80'. if this is indeed an existing instance of your website, just run 'sudo kill -9 <pid>', then try launching your website again. if it's a different process, then you can either kill it (if you recognize it and don't mind killing it) or just try using a different host address for your server.

Comment: but this can't be, because of in the task-manager there is no other httpd process.mabye apache doesn't allow external access for this folder?

Comment: I'm not familiar with lubuntu's task-manager -- can you try running the command I mentioned ("sudo netstat -tlpn | grep ':80'") in a terminal, and share the output from that?

Comment: hmm, for the sake of experimentation, have you tried using a non-standard port? e.g. try something like "listen 0.0.0.0:8001"?

Comment: Ok, so that suggests there is indeed another application currently bound to port 80 (or port 443 -- whichever port you were previously trying to use). My guess would be that it's an apache installation that came with your OS (I know that some Ubuntu versions come with apache pre-installed, anyway), though that should definitely be revealed by netstat. So anyway, this answer is indeed applicable to your question -- you just have to decide between using a non-standard port (which might be inconvenient) and killing whatever process is currently listening on the port you want to use.

Comment: how do i find out which process is using my port?

Comment: "sudo netstat -tulpn | grep ':<port number>'" should do the trick. For example, "sudo netstat -tulpn | grep ':8001'" should show information about the server process you successfully launched just a few minutes ago (assuming it's still running). I know you mentioned that didn't work before...but it really should. To test the apache theory more specifically, you can try: "sudo ps aux | grep apache".

Comment: this still doesn't work, but "sudo ps aux | grep apache" leads to "computername   5731  0.0  0.0  10972  2064 pts/4    S+   19:56   0:00 grep --color=auto apache"

Comment: Well, I guess it's possible that you aren't getting port interference from another application, and that something weird is just going on with port 80 and/or 443 -- like I said, I'm not familiar with the specifics of xampp. That said, I'd be willing to bet that you *are* getting application interference (a much simpler explanation) but I don't know what else to tell you as far as finding the interfering process...

Comment: From a quick search, it looks like another potential issue would be having the same port listed in more than one 'Listen' statement. To detect this, you might try something like this: "grep -ri listen /etc/apache2" (or wherever your xampp server config lives), and see if "Listen 80" comes up multiple times. If so, that would probably be your issue, and you could fix it by removing one of those entries. If not, I'd recommend googling something like "xampp address already in use make_sock ubuntu" and seeing if anything good comes up on SO or on any ubuntu/xampp-specific forums.

Comment: if i removed listen ip:80 and ip:443 and start the server an then type in "sudo netstat -tulpn | grep ':80'" it shows that it is actually listen by xampp. so it has nothing to do with listen.so it is just a problem with /my_website which cannot be shown from external.see my code at the top

Comment: i fugured it out,it was a really stupid error: the folder name was "**M**y_website" from localhost it doesn't matter lowercase/uppercase, from the ip it seemed that it matters.so i renamed the folder to my_website and it works now. :)